# How to open PWA from Google Play in Google Chrome instead of WebView?

Tags: webview, google-play, android-webview, apk, progressive-web-apps

I have a customized PWA for each subdomain of a website. The idea is to have a single PWA on Google Play, which, when installed, will let the user choose a subdomain, redirect him to the subdomain and then prompt him to install the PWA related to the subdomain he has chosen.

The problem is that the PWA installed from Google Play (or directly from apk) opens in a WebView, which does not seem to fire the `berforeinstallprompt` event on the subdomain (When I open the subdomain in Google Chrome, the event is fired correctly). The Add to Home screen option is still available from the WebView menu.

That leaves me with two options, but I cannot get any of them to work:

1) Run PWA installed from Google Play in Google Chrome instead of WebWiev.

2) Find out how to fire `berforeinstallprompt` in WebView.

Is any of them possible? How?

The code that catches the `berforeinstallprompt` event and displays an install button is quite similar to the one on https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/, so the problem should be elsewhere.

```
    var deferredPrompt;
    var button = document.getElementById("install-button");

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        deferredPrompt = e;
        button.style.display = 'block';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`beforeinstallprompt` will only be fired in some cases for example if your app already is installed or if your site doesn't serve all request in https. Also, try to run lighthouse `more tools => developer tools => Audits` and run and see if your app is optimized.

Please describe more what you want to achieve, why are you using subdomains in the PWA?

Comment: The `beforeinstallprompt` is fired when the page is opened in a regular Google Chrome, so the problem should be elsewhere. 

Our web application provides a unique subdomain for each customer. We want each of them to install the PWA directly from their subdomain, so that there is no confusion about where the customer will find his web application. Since users are not yet very familiar with the idea of PWAs, we would like to have a single progressive app available from Google Play that will help the user choose his subdomain, then redirect him there and show the PWA install prompt.

Comment: Now the problem is that when I open an external URL from standalone PWA, it is opened in Android WebView (I hope I am using the term correctly, I mean the simple version of Google Chrome that is used when a link from app is opened). In the WebView, I have the option to Add to Home Screen from the WebView menu, but no `beforeinstallprompt` is fired, so the user sees no notification.

I hope that makes sense, thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's not possible to install a PWA app from a PWA app, because `beforeinstallprompt` will never fire in installed PWA apps. Try to open the user's browser from the app instead. Then they can install it as a PWA

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that. Is there a way to force PWA to open in browser when installed from Google Play? I don't think that this can be solved in the usual way via manifest ("display": "browser"), but I will give it a try.

Comment: I didn't find any way how to open PWA in browser when installed from Google Play yet.